# Flutter : Display app content from Dynamic/Deep Link even if app not installed

Tags: firebase, flutter, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am working on a new events app and I would like users to be able to share events they have created with friends who many not have the app installed on their device yet. I am using the flutterdev share plugin to allow users to share event links through their social media channels, and I would like the invited users to navigate to the event directly when the link is clicked. So they can see the event details and then have the option to install the app if they so choose.

**My question is : how to handle this for users who do not have the app installed on their phone?**

My idea so far has been to develop a flutter web version of my mobile app and send the link as a web url, so the user will be sent to the flutter web version rather than the mobile app.
Is there an easier/smarter way to do this?